# How do silent notification behave once phone got Power off & On

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, core-location, silent-notification

I have a application which tries to grab location of user using silent notification at certain situations. I am able to send silent notification to the phones and able to run the background fetch and get the location back to web-service.

Comparing the user payload of silent notification I am doing some operation(Initiating the location manager & grabbing location from delegate method) while app is in background/suspended mode. This works in all other cases expect one case which is iPhone Power off & turn back ON case.

**Problem:**  According to my observations, Once after phone got power off & turned back ON, The silent notification is being received by iPhones(I confirm this because I hear the sound because I gave sound in payload) but the operation is not happening.

1. Do any one have better understanding how iPhone behaves once after turned-on. will it do the operation after receiving the silent notification ?
2. Does code run anything after phone receiving the silent notification ?
3. I also tried to save the value in UserDefaults before phone getting power off and the value becomes nil after we turned on the power.

Your help, greatly appreciated..!

Comment: I just want to known did you enabled Voip Permission(Push Kit) for you application ?

Comment: @radkrish My application is not a `VoIP` app & I don't think so apple will accept my application if I enable `VoIP`.

Comment: If your app doesn't use VOIP features, you have greater chance of getting rejected for enabling VOIP

Comment: @radkrish I did not enable `VoIP`...!